# Why is this program segfaulting?

Tags: c, shell, eof

I've written a program called [Mathtext](http://azabani.com/snippets/mathtext). This program gives plain text "style" by shifting certain character ranges into Unicode ranges such as 'mathematical letterlike symbols" to produce plain-text italics, bold, serif, etc.

It works as a line-by-line interpreter, like a shell, outputting the translated line after a line is entered. This means that files can be `cat`/piped in to translate an entire file, as well as the fact that you can 'exit' the 'shell' by pressing ^D, which is detected by stdin hitting EOF.

Everything works. However, when I press ^D and exit, it segfaults. I still can't quite grasp what is causing this.

Compiling with `-g -O0` helps a little; I now know that the problem arises from a strlen call in transpose when ^D is pressed. However, transpose should never be called during ^D, as eof is true!

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:31
31    ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S
(gdb) where
#0  __strlen_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/../strlen.S:31
#1  0x0000000000400b0e in transpose (s=0x0, capsDelta=120263, smallDelta=120257, numDelta=0) at mathtext.c:58
#2  0x0000000000400e2b in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe4b8) at mathtext.c:92
```

Comment: please show code around line 92 of mathtext.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most uses of `feof()` are a bug - and this program demonstrates it perfectly in this main loop:

```
char temp[1048576];
do {
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifb"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 119808 - 'A', 119834 - 'a', 120782 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifi"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 119860 - 'A', 119886 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifbi"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 119912 - 'A', 119938 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sans"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 120224 - 'A', 120250 - 'a', 120802 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansb"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 120276 - 'A', 120302 - 'a', 120812 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansi"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 120328 - 'A', 120354 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansbi"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 120380 - 'A', 120406 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "mono"))
        transpose(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), 120432 - 'A', 120458 - 'a', 120822 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "fullwidth"))
        transposeBlock(fgets(temp, 1048576, stdin), '!', '~', 65281 - '!');
    else return help();
} while(!feof(stdin));
```

At end-of-file, `fgets()` will return `NULL`, and then the next invocation of `feof()` will return true.  So the correct approach is to test the return value of your input function - and since you're doing that test anyway, there's no need to call `feof()` (unless you want to distinguish a file error from end-of-file).

```
char temp[1048576];
while (fgets(temp, sizeof temp, stdin) != NULL) {
    if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifb"))
        transpose(temp, 119808 - 'A', 119834 - 'a', 120782 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifi"))
        transpose(temp, 119860 - 'A', 119886 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "serifbi"))
        transpose(temp, 119912 - 'A', 119938 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sans"))
        transpose(temp, 120224 - 'A', 120250 - 'a', 120802 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansb"))
        transpose(temp, 120276 - 'A', 120302 - 'a', 120812 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansi"))
        transpose(temp, 120328 - 'A', 120354 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "sansbi"))
        transpose(temp, 120380 - 'A', 120406 - 'a', 0);
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "mono"))
        transpose(temp, 120432 - 'A', 120458 - 'a', 120822 - '0');
    else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "fullwidth"))
        transposeBlock(temp, '!', '~', 65281 - '!');
    else return help();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your program is dereferencing NULL, since `fgets` returns NULL on error or EOF, and you're passing this directly to transpose which uses the result naively.

Answer (score 1):

`feof` can't predict the future.  It doesn't know it's the end of file until you actually press the ^D key, by which time your program is back waiting for input in `fgets`.  Reading a file wouldn't produce the error because all the input is already present at the beginning.  Check for NULL in your transpose function.

Comment: An easier way to say this is: EOF is not set until you read past the EOF. The last valid read will read UP-TO but not past EOF and thus the read that fails will have exactly 0 bytes to read.